# Is there an idiom or word to describe the action of individuals who verbally tease another person?

Tags: idiom-requests

I have seen some young kids like to tease somebody and laugh at the person and think this is a lots of fun for them, I would like to know if there is any word or idiom  that explains their action.

Comment: Context could be important here to get the right idiom...is the target of the teasing laughing too, or is it more of a bullying of the target, albeit, verbally?

Comment: Assuming that this attention is unwanted, I think "bully" is appropriate.  "Verbal bully" if you want to be more specific.  Don't dress it up in with obscure terms.

Answer (score 4):

bullying or harassment.

From wikipedia entry on bullying:

> Behaviors used to assert such domination can include verbal
>   harassment or threat, physical assault or coercion, and such acts may
>   be directed repeatedly towards particular targets

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom is:

> - [make fun of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+fun+of)  somebody,  *also poke fun at somebody*:
>
>   - to make someone  seem ridiculous by making jokes about them When she first moved north, some people made fun of her southern accent.

(from TFD)

Answer (score 1):

> Take the mickey

-Tease or make fun of

Also sometimes 'take the piss'

[See this link](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/344000.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

> Give *someone* a hard time

This can be used if the persons in question all know each other and the teasing is meant to be fun rather than harassing someone.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, someone who does so is a *bully*, for both verbal and physical forms.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person (in Britain) is a *wind-up merchant* often abbreviated on the internet to WUM.

Notes

1. 'wind' /waind/ is a verb. See the idiom 'to wind someone up'.
2. I don't know if the idiom is used in the US.

Answer (score 0):

One lively idiomatic term is *razz*, which Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, fourth edition (2007) defines as follows:

> **razz** ***v*** To insult and ridicule; NEEDLE ["To nag at someone; criticize regularly and smartingly"], RIDE ["To tease, heckle, make fun of"] : *Is there ever any razzing about the fact that you report to your wife?* {1920+; fr[om] *raspberry* ["A rude and contemptuous expulsion of breath through vibrating lips"]; found in the form *razoo* by 1890}

Answer (score 0):

With the OP's "tease" in mind, I'm going to propose the word *josh*.

**Josh:** (verb)   "Tease (someone) in a playful way. *He loved to josh people"* (Oxford Dictionaries).

Answer (score -1):

**Pester** could work! Its definition (according to [Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pester) is "to harass with petty irritations : annoy."

Comment: The definition "to harass with petty irritations" seems to have come from definition 2 of [Merriam-Webster's entry for _pester_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pester) ("to harass with petty irritations :  annoy"). I have added a link to that page of the MW site and credited the source in your answer. In future answers at this site, please include such citations. Thanks!